# Should 'Today' and 'Tomorrow' be capitalised?

Tags: writing, capitalization

I always wonder whether 'today' and 'tomorrow' should be capitalised. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 14):

Today and Tomorrow are not capitalized because they are not really names, nor are they proper nouns.

They are capitalized only if they appear at the beginning of a sentence, or if you are making a title for some sort of event such as "The Today News". Otherwise, it is a plain old regular word.

I have written this **today** and may or may not get an upvote for it **tomorrow**
:D

Answer (score 5):

The words *today*, *tomorrow* and *yesterday* are not capitalized.

However, *Monday*, *Tuesday*, *Wednesday*, *Thursday*, *Friday*, *Saturday* and *Sunday* are capitalized.

Answer (score 5):

The words *today* and *tomorrow* are only ever capitalized in titles:

> *The Today Show* (TV program)
>
> *Tomorrow Never Knows* (Beatles song)

But in everyday speech, these words are left lower-cased:

> I'm going to take it easy today. I have a big day tomorrow.

Edit per Christian's comment:

English does not capitalize nouns unless they are so-called *proper nouns*, by which I do not mean *proper* in the British sense of being "in order" or "the way a thing should be done," but instead nouns that are used as actual names for people or places or ideas that are represented in titular form. The other variety of nouns are called *common nouns*, and they refer to everyday things that are not singled out for such special naming. Unlike German, in which every noun is capitalized, common nouns in English are not singled out for special treatment (unless, of course, they come at the beginning of a sentence, or are used as class identifiers in a poetic sense: occasionally you will see *truth* or *beauty* written as *Truth* or *Beauty*, signifying that these represent special philosophically representative uses of the terms).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP is interested in the reason behind it as well...

Comment: They are also capitalized at the beginning of a sentence, but I'm pretty sure that's stating the obvious.

Comment: @Lo'oris: I was noting that in my edit probably at the same time you were typing this comment.

Answer (score -1):

"Today" is not a <strike><strike>noun (name)</strike> *pronoun*</strike> *proper noun*, unlike "Monday" or "Friday", therefore, no, they're not capitalized.
It's akin to "boy" and "Tom" (for example).

Comment: _Today_ can be a noun. When I say "Today is going to be a great day", I use _today_ as a noun. Unlike the names for days of the week though, it can be used on _any_ day to refer to "this present day".

Comment: @Tragicomic - Good point. Maybe it has something to do with the *type* of noun?

Comment: I think "important words" in a sentence should be capitalized...but note that not in all cases!!

Comment: @Hazro City - That sounds awfully subjective..

Comment: Why is "today" in "Today is going to be a great day" any more of a noun deserving capitalization than "this" in "this is going to be a great day"?

Comment: Um, so *boy* is not a noun?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: I was just commenting on on the fact that it _is_ a noun (as opposed to what is said in the answer), not that it should be capitalized. It's capitalized in my example since it was at the beginning of my example sentence:-).

Comment: About why the names of the days of the week are capitalized unlike, say, the names of seasons, I suspect the answer may lie in the etymology of these names (not sure, though).

Comment: @RegDwight - *boy* is not a **name**. @Tragicomic - A think "name" is the key to the question...

Comment: @Tragicomic: [there's a question for that](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1271/why-are-days-of-the-week-proper-nouns), though the answer seems to be unclear.

Comment: @Christian: my comment was a subtle hint that your answer seems to equate noun and name, which are not the same. The distinction you are looking for is that between common nouns and proper ones.

Comment: @RegDwight - Ah, right you are. I'm please to know that at least someone came up with a fully qualified answer.

Comment: @Christian: thanks for the edit, but *pronoun* is something different yet again. *Me*, *he*, and *ours* are pronouns; *Monday* and *Friday* are not.

Comment: @RegDwight - Aw god...I knew I should have taken some coffee this morning! On the upside, I just got an editor badge for all those repeated edits :D